# weird affectation to a variable in foreachPartition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I attempt a transactionCount variable to be 100 and I get 0. I have an RDD with always, only one partition. I have a piece of code like this which processes the RDD:

```
var transactionCount = -1

payment_rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
  // this line affect 100 to transactionCount  since the I have 100 record 
  // in my RDD so in my partition
  transactionCount = partitionOfRecords.size
  partitionOfRecords.foreach { record =>
      // I process each record
  }
  try {
    // this line keep 100 to transactionCount 

    //another process
  }
  catch {
    case _: Throwable => {
      // I never pass here
      log.error("Cannot process correctly")
      transactionCount = 0
    }
  }
}
return transactionCount
```

I get in return -1 despite 100 and I can't understand why.
Do you have any idea or a better solution? Thanks

Comment: May be your `try` block raising exception always.

Comment: Such mutation is generally not a good idea, specially with distribution

Comment: as I mention in the comment, It never rise an exception

Comment: I edit my question to be more explicit with the behavior of my process. Please don't make a down If you don't see the comment line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute this code:

- Spark computes closure.
- Serializes each variable required by closure and send it to the executors.
- When code is executed each executor modifies local copy of the deserialized variable.

This is described and explained in [programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-a-nameclosureslinka)

Also you cannot do this:

```
transactionCount = partitionOfRecords.size
```

`Iterators` can be traversed only once and will be empty after you compute size.

I'd use `Try` and accumulator:

```
val transactionCount = spark.sparkContext.longAccumulator

rdd.foreach { record => {
   if Try {
     // your code goes here
   }.isSuccess transactionCount.add(1L)
}}
```